Sister cat stealing sister's kittens and trying to feed with no milk
My 1 year old keeps stealing her sister's kittens.  The 1 year old is not fixed, and never been pregnant.  She is 100% indoor cat.  The babies are 26 days today.  This has been going on for 3 days now.  The mother is not wanting to feed but twice a day now cause all the babies are attached to the 1 year old for some reason.  I've separated her from the litter and she clawed the door to so bad I probably won't get my security deposit back.  I locked her in her carrier she clawed her way out. I even threatened her with a bath if she did it again.  She did so I did.  Still didn't work.  Now one of the babies is sticky looking and got the cry they get when their dying.  I've had many liters in my life and never had a situation like this.  I can't afford the vet or even kitten milk.  My income went from $6376 to $198 over night.  I don't know what I'm going to do for rent in a few days.  I can't save the dying one, hopefully someone has some advise so I can prevent any more deaths.

My bad the title should say cat.  Not car.

Typo fixed. But this question has been asked before; it isn't rare behavior.

I think I'd find someone else to house the problem cat until the kittens are weaned.
